# Pytorch mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied

Tags: neural-network, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, image-classification, pytorch

The error message shows

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x32768 and 512x256)
```

I have built the following model:

```
def classifier_block(input, output, kernel_size, stride, last_layer=False):
  if not last_layer:
    x = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(input, output, kernel_size, stride, padding=3),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(output),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
    )
  else:
    x = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(input, output, kernel_size, stride),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
    )
  return x

class Classifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, output):
    super(Classifier, self).__init__()
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        classifier_block(input_dim, 64, 7, 2),
        classifier_block(64, 64, 3, 2),
        classifier_block(64, 128, 3, 2),
        classifier_block(128, 256, 3, 2),
        classifier_block(256, 512, 3, 2, True)
    )
    print('CLF: ',self.classifier)
    
    self.linear = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512, 256),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(256, 128),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(128, 64),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(64, output)
    )
    print('Linear: ', self.linear)
  
  def forward(self, image):
    print('IMG: ', image.shape)
    x = self.classifier(image)
    print('X: ', x.shape)
    return self.linear(x.view(len(x), -1))
```

The input images are of size `512x512`. Here is my training block:

```
loss_train = []
loss_val = []

for epoch in range(epochs):
  print('Epoch: {}/{}'.format(epoch, epochs))
  total_train = 0
  correct_train = 0
  cumloss_train = 0
  classifier.train()
  for batch, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
    x = x.to(device)
    print(x.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    output = classifier(x)
    loss = criterion(output, y.to(device))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print('Loss: {}'.format(loss))
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `torchsummary` could help a lot to figure out the size of your linear layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `forward`, the image first passes through some convolutional layers (i.e. `self.classifier`), then it is flattened, then passed through some linear layers (i.e. `self.linear`).

The problem is the dimensionality of the flattened tensor does not match the expected input for `self.linear`. The last dimension of the flatened tensor is expected to be 512 (see the `in_features` parameter of [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html)), but it actually is 32768, according to the error you get.

You may change `nn.Linear(512, 256)` with `nn.Linear(41472, 256)` to fix the mismatch.

Comment: Gives this error after setting this:  ```nn.Linear(32768, 256)```
> RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x41472 and 32768x256)

Comment: This suggests that your images do not have the same size. They must have the same size.

Comment: I have resized all the images to 512x512 using ```transforms.Resize([512, 512])```

Comment: Obtaining different dimensionalities after the convolutional layers is clear evidence of different input sizes. Some possible causes are that either you added the transformation after having the initial error of your question (then you can simply update the `in_features` of the said linear layer) or that some of your images are not being resized (e.g. validation images). You can debug of add traces to ensure that the size of the images is always the same.

Comment: setting ```nn.Linear(41472, 256)``` solves the issue apparently.

Comment: Please, consider upvoting the answer if it was useful and accepting it if you consider it correct (or, alternatively, please describe why you think it's not or what is not clear).